# What side affects are there from Windows user impersonation?

Tags: windows, winapi, impersonation

In Windows, a program can get a user access token by calling [`LogonUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx), [`OpenProcessToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295(v=vs.85).aspx), SSPI functions, and a couple others. Once you have the token, there are quite a few functions that you can pass this token into in order to do things as this user. Do these sort of actions typically have side effects for the "parent" process?

For example, you can load the user's profile (registry settings, etc) via [`LoadUserProfile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281(v=vs.85).aspx). Amongst other things, `LoadUserProfile` will load the user's registry hive into `HKEY_USERS` and map `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` to it. From the parent process' perspective, does this alter `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`? Or is it only "visible" after starting a new process as that user via [`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx), impersonating in the current process via [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx), etc?

Comment: By parent process, I meant the process that is calling LogonUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per its [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281.aspx), `LoadUserProfile()` returns a handle to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key that was loaded.  You can then pass that handle to Registry functions, and they will access that user's data.  `LoadUserProfile()` does not affect the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key associated with the user that is running the calling process.

Impersonation CAN affect the calling process's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key, but typically WILL NOT:

[Predefined Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724836.aspx)

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER
>   ...
>   The mapping between HKEY_CURRENT_USER and HKEY_USERS is **per process and is established the first time the process references HKEY_CURRENT_USER**. The mapping is based on the **security context of the first thread to reference HKEY_CURRENT_USER**. If this security context does not have a registry hive loaded in HKEY_USERS, the mapping is established with HKEY_USERS.Default. **After this mapping is established it persists, even if the security context of the thread changes**.

So, if you are impersonating a user when you use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` for the first time, then it will map to that user's key for the duration of the process.  Raymond Chen even said as much on his blog:

[Is it wrong to call SHFileOperation from a service? Revised](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/11/21/10574758.aspx)

> The registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER is  bound to the current user at the time the key is first accessed by a process:
>   ...
>   This means that if you impersonate a user, and then access HKEY_CURRENT_USER, then that binds HKEY_CURRENT_USER to the impersonated user. Even if you stop impersonating, future references to HKEY_CURRENT_USER will still refer to that user.

However, for the majority of cases, you will likely access the Registry before you impersonate anyone, or you will not access the Registry while impersonating, so `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` will typically map to the user that the app is running as.  If a thread is impersonating a user and needs to access that user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key, use `OpenThreadToken()` (if you don't already have the token) and `LoadUserProfile()` to get that user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` handle.

Comment: See also [Is it wrong to call SHFileOperation from a service? Revised](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/11/21/10574758.aspx) (The Old New Thing).

Comment: For the user's `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values,  call [`ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: To redirect `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` to the loaded profile key, call [`RegOverridePredefKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @eryksun: true about `RegOverridePredefKey()`, though it is intended to be used only by installers to monitor changes being made to the Registry during installation.